# Spark : what does "expr" mean?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm learning Spark in Java, I noticed that to add a column we can use

```
dataset.withColumn("name", expr(something))
```

I want to know what is the syntaxe of `expr` ? Is it a regular expression ? I didn't find manual on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function 'expr' expects a string that contains a bit of SQL that defines a column. For example:

```
val df = List("1AB","2XX","3Y").toDF("id")
df.withColumn("first2OfID", expr("substr(id,1,2)")).show

+---+----------+
| id|first2OfID|
+---+----------+
|1AB|        1A|
|2XX|        2X|
| 3Y|        3Y|
+---+----------+
```

Comment: Hi thank you, now I understand. One more question : Is it possible to create only with expr() without dataset ?

Comment: I think you are asking can you write plain SQL? The answer is yes, using spark.sql("select * from dataset") noting your data has to be registered in spark, e.g. Reading it from hive, or using dataframe.registerTempTable